# How to select from four tables with similar rows and insert into 1 table using SQL Server through a stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I have 4 similar tables with huge volume of data and I would like to insert required columns from 4 tables into 1 user defined table for building a report and how can I do that using a stored procedure?

I tried using `Union` to pull data from all 4 tables and I can use an `Insert` statement to insert into the table.

How would I create a stored procedure to insert the values into a table?

Comment: Is your question just "How do I make a stored procedure in SQL Server?"  If so, then just Google that, Microsoft has tons of doc on this.  For example, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/create-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: You need to make an effort to clarify exactly what you require help with. Posting what you have tried would help. And of course doing your research first.

Answer (score 0):

```
create proc what_seems_to_be_my_first_proc
as begin
 insert ....  <--copy-paste your insert with unions here
end
```

Comment: While this code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive-feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.